# executing cmd command from nodeJS app while running on iisnode doesn't work

Tags: node.js, iis, perforce, iisnode

We have a web app the that executes a small command from CMD with

```
require('child_process').execSync
```

All worked perfectly when I was running the service with `npm start` but the moment that we moved it to iisnode it stopped working. For example:`p4 depots` doesn't work anymore.

IIS is run by Admin user.

If I run the command from cmd directly it works, but when I call it from the iisnode it doesn't.

The error:

> {"Error":true,"Message":"Error executing p4 CMD","Origmsg":{"killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"cmd":"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"p4 depots\""}}

Did anyone had the same issue in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem was only with perforce.
The solution was to do `p4 set -s P4PORT` + user + password.
The "-s" option saves the setting to all of the users on the current machine.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You should probably run 'p4 set -s' and look at all the settings for your new service, and confirm whether there are other settings you are missing besides P4PORT, for example 'P4USER', 'P4CLIENT', etc.

Comment: You are right but for my specific case this was enough :)